# TSQL Summary by account, what is the cleanest way to approach this?

Tags: t-sql, sum

I am trying to total by account, the expenses & income per account. There are multiples of both the income & the expenses per account. I am struggling with this as  am still learning SQL and thought that someone else likely has already addressed this?  I sure would appreciate the help!

I know that this SQL server code is not correct but it at least gives a bit clearer picture of what I am attempting to do.

IF(SELECT(OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#Total'))) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Total

declare @Expenses   decimal(13,2),
      @income   decimal(13,2)

set @expenses =   sum(EXP_CHILD_CARE_AMOUNT) 
                + sum(EXP_FOOD_AMOUNT) 
                + sum(EXP_LIFE_INSURANCE_AMOUNT)
                + sum(EXP_TRANSPORTATION_AMOUNT)
            + sum(EXP_TUITION_AMOUNT)
                + sum(EXP_USER_2_AMOUNT)
            + sum(EXP_USER_3_AMOUNT)
                + sum(EXP_UTILITIES_AMOUNT)

set  @income = (sum(NET_PAY_AMOUNT) 
                + sum(OTHER_INCOME_AMOUNT)

SELECT  F.LOAN_NUMBER, @Income, @Expenses

INTO  #Total
FROM  OPENQUERY(SvrLink, '

SELECT   F.Account, @Income, @Expenses

FROM  finances F
        inner join account a on(a.Account = f.Account)
           where a.balance > 0

FETCH ONLY WITH UR ')

Comment: What are your table names? Do EXP_CHILD_CARE_AMOUNT and EXP_FOOD_AMOUNT columns live in the same table?  What about NET_PAY_AMOUNT and OTHER_INCOME_AMOUNT?

Answer (score 0):

...ok, assuming that some fields are grouped into the same table (if not you'll just have to write the joins), you just need 1 query.  (I wish all languages were as concise...)
@AccountId is your desired account id.

```
SELECT l.LOAN_NUMBER, l.AccountId,
    (SELECT sum(EXP_CHILD_CARE_AMOUNT) + sum(EXP_FOOD_AMOUNT) + 
      sum(EXP_LIFE_INSURANCE_AMOUNT) + sum(EXP_TRANSPORTATION_AMOUNT) + 
      sum(EXP_TUITION_AMOUNT) + sum(EXP_USER_2_AMOUNT) + 
      sum(EXP_USER_3_AMOUNT) + sum(EXP_UTILITIES_AMOUNT) 
      as ExpenseTotal FROM Expenses_Guessing_The_Table_Name
      WHERE AccountId = @AccountId) as ExpenseTotal,
    (SELECT sum(NET_PAY_AMOUNT) + sum(OTHER_INCOME_AMOUNT) as IncomeTotal
      FROM Income_Guessing_The_Table_Name
      WHERE AccountId = @AccountId) as IncomeTotal
    FROM Loans l 
    WHERE  l.AccountId = @AccountId AND l.Balance > 0
```

Comment: Yes all the columns live in the same table. The second table is only to validate the account still has a balance.I will give this a whirl, So appreciate the help..

Comment: received this error:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "as" was found following "WHERE F.Loan_Number".  Expected tokens may include:  "<interval_qualifier>".  SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: here is code:  
SELECT LOAN_NUMBER,  
    (SELECT sum(EXP_CHILD_CARE_AMOUNT) + sum(EXP_FOOD_AMOUNT) + 
      sum(EXP_LIFE_INSURANCE_AMOUNT) + sum(EXP_TRANSPORTATION_AMOUNT) + 
      sum(EXP_TUITION_AMOUNT) + sum(EXP_USER_2_AMOUNT) + 
      sum(EXP_USER_3_AMOUNT) + sum(EXP_UTILITIES_AMOUNT) 
      as ExpenseTotal FROM  Financials F
      WHERE F.Loan_Number as ExpenseTotal,
      
    (SELECT sum(NET_PAY_AMOUNT) + sum(OTHER_INCOME_AMOUNT) as IncomeTotal
      FROM Financials
      WHERE L.Loan_Number as IncomeTotal
    FROM Loan L
    WHERE  L.First_Principal_Balance > 0

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis before the "AS ExpenseTotal"

Comment: Tried again  
SELECT LOAN_NUMBER,  
    (SELECT sum(EXP_CHILD_CARE_AMOUNT) + sum(EXP_FOOD_AMOUNT) + 
      sum(EXP_LIFE_INSURANCE_AMOUNT) + sum(EXP_TRANSPORTATION_AMOUNT) + 
      sum(EXP_TUITION_AMOUNT) + sum(EXP_USER_2_AMOUNT) + 
      sum(EXP_USER_3_AMOUNT) + sum(EXP_UTILITIES_AMOUNT) 
      as ExpenseTotal)
       FROM FINANCIALS      
      
    (SELECT sum(NET_PAY_AMOUNT) + sum(OTHER_INCOME_AMOUNT) as IncomeTotal)
      FROM FINANCIALS
 
    FROM LOAN L
    WHERE  L.First_Principal_Balance > 0

Comment: New Error:  SQL0104N  An unexpected token ")" was found following "as ExpenseTotal".  Expected tokens may include:  "<table_expr>".  SQLSTATE=42601".

Comment: The code I pasted above is not what you're trying.  Looking at what you're pasting now, try this:  SELECT LOAN_NUMBER,  
(SELECT sum(EXP_CHILD_CARE_AMOUNT) + sum(EXP_FOOD_AMOUNT) + sum(EXP_LIFE_INSURANCE_AMOUNT) + sum(EXP_TRANSPORTATION_AMOUNT) +
   sum(EXP_TUITION_AMOUNT) + sum(EXP_USER_2_AMOUNT) + sum(EXP_USER_3_AMOUNT) + sum(EXP_UTILITIES_AMOUNT) FROM FINANCIALS) as ExpenseTotal,
(SELECT sum(NET_PAY_AMOUNT) + sum(OTHER_INCOME_AMOUNT) FROM FINANCIALS) as IncomeTotal
FROM LOAN L
WHERE L.First_Principal_Balance > 0

Comment: One more crucial thing that you dropped in my initial post and I missed in my latest response... You need to add a where clause entry to each subquery to filter by AccountID (or LoanID?) to force the filter by just that loan number.  Otherwise you'll get the same 2 numbers reported for each row.  [WHERE AccountId = @AccountId]

Comment: I think matched yours,expense SELECT  F.LOAN_NUMBER,  (SELECT(SUM(EXP_CHILD_CARE_AMOUNT) + SUM(EXP_FOOD_AMOUNT) + SUM(EXP_LIFE_INSURANCE_AMOUNT) + SUM(EXP_TRANSPORTATION_AMOUNT) + SUM(EXP_TUITION_AMOUNT)+ SUM(EXP_USER_1_AMOUNT) + SUM(EXP_USER_2_AMOUNT) + SUM(EXP_USER_3_AMOUNT) + SUM(EXP_UTILITIES_AMOUNT)FROM FINANCIAL F) AS ExpenseTotal, 
(SELECT(SUM(MORTGAGOR_NET_PAY_AMOUNT) +  SUM(MORTGAGOR_OTHER_INCOME_AMOUNT) AS IncomeTotal FROM FINANCIAL F 
INNER JOIN BDE.LOAN_V a ON F.LOAN_NUMBER = A.LOAN_NUMBER
WHERE A.FIRST_PRINCIPAL_BALANCE> 0  GROUP BY F.LOAN_NUMBER, ORDER BY F.LOAN_NUMBER

Comment: new error OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKBDE" returned message "[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "FROM" was found following "XP_UTILITIES_AMOUNT)".  Expected tokens may include:  ")".  SQLSTATE=42601
".
Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKBDE".

Comment: Hey JMS49, it looks like you're using a linked server to DB2 to pass SQL through AND you're possibly using a custom extended procedure XP_UTILITIES_AMOUNT.  I should have seen the "FETCH ONLY WITH UR" bit and understood the DB2 slant, my bad.  The next step for you is to figure out where XP_UTILITIES_AMOUNT is getting invoked (not in any code you've posted) and tracing that error down.  Good luck.